# Error runtime 91 and 429

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

This code feels like Schrodinger is executing it. If I open the project and run the code, I won't get any errors at all. If I view the code to edit or add anything, the first time I run the code, I get 'Run-time error 91'. If I try to run it a second time, making no changes, I get 'Run-time error 429' (ActiveX component can't create object).

What I'm trying to achieve is to find the row (BuildSel) in a range on worksheet (Ref) that has the same value as what's selected in a list on a userform (BuildList). Then once the row is found, to take data from that row and columns A and B, and put them in textbox's on my userform. Is my code right and ActiveX making the error? I apologize for terrible coding too.

EDIT: The listbox is on a multipage on my userform. I first noticed the issue today when I tried adding another listbox on a different page.

```
Private Sub BuildList_Click()
    Dim Ref As Worksheet, BuildSel As Long

    Set Ref = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ref")

    BuildSel = Ref.Range("B2", Ref.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(BuildList.Value, lookat:=xlPart).Row
    BuilderText.Value = Ref.Range("A" & BuildSel).Value
    CompNameText.Value = Ref.Range("B" & BuildSel).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: BuildSel is improperly defined. It should say `Dim BuildSel As Variant`
I would put this as an answer to my own question, but since I can't explain why this fixed the problem, nor do I want to promote my code as being a good example of proper code, I'll put it here as a comment. I'll leave the question up to the moderators to decide whether it would be helpful to others or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why altering 'BuildSel' to variant makes it work, but the code as it stands has no error checking for when there is no matching list item to be found

The following code should be better suited for usage:

```
Private Sub BuildList_Click()
    Dim Ref As Worksheet: Set Ref = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ref")
    Dim BuildSel As Range
    With Ref
        Set BuildSel = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find _
            (BuildList.Value, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not BuildSel Is Nothing Then
            BuilderText.Value = .Range("A" & BuildSel.Row).Value
            CompNameText.Value = .Range("B" & BuildSel.Row).Value
        Else
            BuilderText.Value = ""
            CompNameText.Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thakns Flephal for your more efficient code. That would in fact achieve what I was wanting and wouldn't leave any room for error. I'm going to change my code to something like what you've suggested because the line I made is pretty messy. BuildSel should never be `Nothing` but I guess that may not have been the case since I was getting errors. Thank you for the help!!